# Trying to multiply specific columns, by a portion of multiple rows in Pandas DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I am trying to multiply a few specific columns by a portion of multiple rows and creating a new column from every result. I could not really find an answer to my question in previous stackoverflow questions or on google, so maybe one of you can help.

I would like to point out that I am quite the beginner in Python, so apologies ahead for any obvious questions or strange code.

This is how my DataFrame currently looks like:
[image]

So, for the column Rank of Hospital by Doctor_1, I want to multiply all its numbers by the values of the first row of column Rank of Doctor by Hospital_1 until column Rank of Doctor by Hospital_10. Which would result in:

```
1*1
2*1
3*1
4*4
...
```

and so on.
I want to do this for every Doctor_ column. So for Doctor_2 its values should be multiplied by the second row of all those ten columns (Rank of Doctor by Hospital_. Doctor_3, multiplied by the third row etc.

So far, I have transposed the Rank of Doctor by Hospital_ columns in a new DataFrame:
[image]

and tried to multiply this by a DataFrame of the Rank of Hospital by Doctor_ columns. Here the first column of the first df should be multiplied by the first column of the second df. (and second column * second column, etc.):
[image]

But my current formula

```
preferences_of_doctors_and_hospitals_doctors_ranking.mul(preferences_of_doctors_and_hospitals_hospitals_ranking_transposed)
```

is obviously not working:
[image]

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong and how I could fix this? Maybe I could write a for loop so that a new column is created for every multiplication of columns? So Multiplication_column_1 of DF3 = Column 1 of DF1 * Column 1 of DF2 and Multiplication_column_2 of DF3 = Column 2 of DF1 * Column 2 of DF2.

Thank you in advance!

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiple 2d arrays created by filtering column with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) first:

```
arr = df.filter(like='Rank of Hospital by').values * df.filter(like='Rank of Doctor by').values
```

Or:

```
arr = (preferences_of_doctors_and_hospitals_doctors_ranking.values * 
       preferences_of_doctors_and_hospitals_hospitals_ranking_transposed.values)
```

***Notice*** - necessary is same ordering of columns, same length of columns names and index in both filtered DataFrames.

Get 2d array, so create DataFrame by constructor and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index).add_prefix('Multiplied '))
```

Comment: Thank you Jezrael for your answer!

Comment: One more small question if you have the time, how could I change ('Multiplied') so that it starts at 1 and not at 0?

Comment: @Jeff - Can you check `df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns= np.arange(1, arr.shape[1] + 1)).add_prefix('Multiplied '))` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[6,7,8,9,10]})
df["mul"] = df["A"] * df["B"]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  mul
0  1   6    6
1  2   7   14
2  3   8   24
3  4   9   36
4  5  10   50
```

If I understood the question correctly I think you way over complicated it.
You can just create another column telling pandas to give it the value of first column multiplied by second column.

More similar to your specific case with more than 2 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[6,7,8,9,10], "C":[11,12,13,14,15]})
df["mul"] = df["A"] * df["B"] * df["C"]
```

Comment: This could work, but then I would have to manually do that for all columns. However, I want to do it for all of them at the same time.

Comment: you can chain them. By just continuing the multiplication I may have misunderstood the question but i did not see any dynamic length multiplications, added another example above.